# How to make arrow transition on button:hover instead of span:hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a button with an arrow inside. Currently, the arrow transitions to the right when the arrow inside of the button is hovered, but I would like the arrow to transition when the button is hovered.

[image: Button with CSS arrow]

[image: Arrow on hover]

```css
button {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 22.6px;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 16px 32px 16px 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.btn-black {
    border: 4px solid #000000;
    color: #000000;
}
.btn-grey {
    border: 4px solid #45423C;
    color: #45423C;
}
.arrow {
    height: 2px;
    width: 25px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.arrow:hover {
    transition: all .4s ease;
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.arrow-black {
    background: black;
}
.arrow-grey{
    background: #45423C;
}
.arrow:before, .arrow:after {
    content: "";
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 30%;
}
.arrow:before {
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.arrow:after {
    right: -2px;
    top: -3px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-black"><span class="arrow arrow-black"></span>WHO WE ARE</button>
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @biberman the link is on the post ( http://jsfiddle.net/sqkpx79n/ ) but in case the code is not showing on js fiddle, I added the code as a snippet as well. Thank you for bringing that to my attention

Comment: `button:hover .arrow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a transition issue since it is defined only for the hovered arrow. If you move it to `.arrow` itself the transition is working in both directions. And if you want the "animation" take effect when the button is hovered then define `:hover` for the button.

**Working example**:

```css
button {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22.6px;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 16px 32px 16px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-black {
  border: 4px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
}

.btn-grey {
  border: 4px solid #45423C;
  color: #45423C;
}

.arrow {
  height: 2px;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

button:hover .arrow {
  width: 35px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.arrow-black {
  background: black;
}

.arrow-grey {
  background: #45423C;
}

.arrow:before,
.arrow:after {
  content: "";
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 30%;
}

.arrow:before {
  right: -2px;
  bottom: -3px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arrow:after {
  right: -2px;
  top: -3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-black">
  <span class="arrow arrow-black"></span>
  WHO WE ARE
</button>
```